# String mask element name UITests

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have a text on my screen that is presented like:

```
@"New element #13"
```

How can I make universal test for it and reach this element by mask?

```
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"New element #**"] tap];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to match text via a regular expression.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
NSString *format = "label BEGINSWITH 'New element #'";
NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] initWithFormat:format];
XCUIElement *element = [app.buttons elementMatchingPredicate:predicate];
[element tap];
```

Note that if there are more than one button that matches the predicate Xcode might raise an exception.

You can find a Swift example (and working app) in [my post on UI Testing](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#picker-with-multiple-wheels).